# Bound for Expectation value of dependent random variables

Tags: probability, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-approximation

Let $X$,$Y$ be dependent random variables, $\mu_x$ and $\mu_y$ their expectation values and let $a_1$ and $a_2$ be natural numbers. Then I need a bound for the following formula:

$$ \mathbb{E} [(X-\mu_x)^{a_1} * (Y - \mu_y)^{a_2} ] \leq ??? $$

I dont have any informations about the distributions so a direct calculation is not possible.

Comment: Even for independent random variables, there is no guarantee that the desired expectation is finite. For example, there are random variables with finite mean and unbounded variance.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. We can assume that the desired expectation is finite. Do you think I can estimate with supremums norm or some other stuff?